# How to Query Subdocuments with variable names

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a json document I've imported to a mongodb that looks similar to the test data below:

```
[
    {
        "subject_id": "1",
        "name": "Bob",
        "dob": "12/31/00",
        "gender": "Male",
        "visits": {
            "12/31/15": {
                "age": "17",
                "visit_category": "Baseline Visit"
            },
            "12/31/16": {
                "age": "18",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "12/31/17": {
                "age": "18",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "XXX123": {
                "completed_by": "Sally",
                "label_on_sample": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "subject_id": "2",
        "name": null,
        "dob": "1/1/01",
        "gender": "Female",
        "visits": {
            "1/1/11": {
                "age": "10",
                "visit_category": "Baseline Visit"
            },
            "1/1/12": {
                "age": "11",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/13": {
                "age": "12",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/14": {
                "age": "13",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            },
            "1/1/15": {
                "age": "14",
                "visit_category": "Follow Up Visit"
            }
        },
        "samples": {
            "YYY456": {
                "completed_by": null,
                "label_on_sample": "2"
            },
            "ZZZ789": {
                "completed_by": "Sally",
                "label_on_sample": "2"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I'd like to query info within the visit dates or samples, but I believe I am getting hung up because of their variable titles. What is the best way to query all of the subdocuments.

```
filter_by = {'subject.samples': {'$elemMatch': {'visit_category': "Follow Up Visit" }}}
data = db['subject'].find(filter_by)
print(data.count())
```

Returns 0. How would I format some kind of wildcard after 'subject.samples' to get this to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you may want to correct your document structure to have the visits key contain an *array of visits*.

Mongo allows for one to do a [pipeline query that converts an object to an array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) but I don't think this scales easily for large collections without considering other means to optimise the search.

Here now is how I will query for total number of visits matching "Follow Up Visit"

```
pipeline =  [
      {
         '$project': {
            'visits': { '$objectToArray': '$visits' }
         }
      },
     {
         '$unwind': '$visits'
     },
     {
        '$match': {
            'visits.v.visit_category': 'Follow Up Visit'
        }
     },
     {
        '$count': 'count'
     }
]
cur = db.patient.aggregate(pipeline)
result = next(cur)

print(result['count'])
```